# I want Lotus Domino to only send one email to users that are both recipients and members of a cc'ed lotus group

Tags: smtp, email, ibm-domino

Lotus Domino 7 and now Lotus Domino 8.5

The scenario:

A@mycompany writes an email to b@internet and cc's it to group@mycompany. A@mycompany is a member of group@mycompany.

With the initial email Domino is intelligent enough to not send the email which a@mycompany just wrote to a@mycompany again.

But when b@internet answers to all (a@mycompany + group@mycompany) then a@mycompany gets this email twice, because he is not only the author but also a member of group@mycompany.

During the smtp session the email is sent once with the recipients set to a@mycompany and group@mycompany and a single esmtp id. So Domino should well be able to see that the mail should only be sent to a@mycompany once.

Can I make Lotus Domino behave in this sane fashion?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that Domino thinks A@mycompany.com (the direct recipient of the reply) is different from A/your_notes_domain (the group member).

Try adding A@mycompany.com as an alias in the User field.