# Some users sometimes recieves two identical email

Tags: email, groups, lotus-notes, ibm-domino

We have problem in our Lotus Notes/Domino environment, sometimes users recieve two identical emails (at the same time) from a recipient.

I am not sure, but I think this happens if I send an email to a group of people using email address and someone in that group respond or respond to all. 
(i.e there is a group in domino directory that can be sent to using an email address like group1@acme.com)

so even if the email address is to the "internal company" it seem to take a trip to the internet maybe?

anyone else seen this?

We are running latest version on Server and client (8.5.3)

Comment: looks like this question is similar http://serverfault.com/questions/94523/i-want-lotus-domino-to-only-send-one-email-to-users-that-are-both-recipients-and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A notes.ini parameter was introduced to fix this in Notes 8.5.3

See here
Duplicate message received when recipient also member of group being sent to
https://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21266166

Answer (score 1):

You are probably seeing "[Duplicate messages are received when 'Exhaustive Lookup' is enabled](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21225032)"

> Lotus Notes recipients sometimes receive duplicate messages when "Exhaustive Lookup" is enabled in a Domino server's Configuration Settings document's Router/SMTP > Basics tab.
>
> ...
>
> This scenario can occur if an internal Notes user sends a message to an internal Notes recipient and to a group of which that recipient is a member, depending on the format of the addresses.
>
> ...
>
> **Resolving the problem**
>
> This issue was reported to Quality Engineering as SPR# KGEW6FVUGB.
>
> To resolve the issue, disable "Exhaustive Lookup" in the Configuration document on the Router/SMTP Basic tab.